# How to return a list of users who have the same city code as the user logged in the system?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm finding it difficult to return a list of users who have in common the same city (IdCity) as the user logged into the system.
Instead of returning the various users it creates redundancy and returns the same user logged in.
Btw I changed those models properties because it was written in Portuguese...

User Model

```
public partial class TblUser
{

        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public int IdCity { get; set; }

        public virtual TblCity TblCity { get; set; }
}
```

City Model

```
public partial class TblCity
{

        [Key]

        public int IdCity { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

}
```

Procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_Citizen]
@IdCity int
AS
BEGIN
Select Name,t1.City from TblUser t1 
join TblCity t2 on t2.IdCity = t1.IdCity
where t1.IdCity= @IdCity
END
```

Action

```
 public ActionResult List()
        {
            List<TblUser> _users = new List<TblUser>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conexao.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                string sql = "SP_Citizen";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    var logged = User.Identity.Name;
                    int userId = db.TblUser.Where(x => x.Name== logged).FirstOrDefault().IdCity;

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    TblUser citizen= new TblUser();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCity", userId);
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr != null)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                citizen.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                                citizen.City= dr["City"].ToString();
                                _users .Add(citizen);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(_usuarios);
        }
```

[image]

how to solve this?

Comment: It is a common error. You are creating the instance of the Citizen just one time outside the loop that add a citizen to the list. The result: Same citizen instance added many time to the list, just changing the values of the same instance until you reach the end. Declare and initialize inside the loop

Comment: @Steve i appreciate that, this solve the problem

Comment: Curious why you need a join, you only filter on the foreign key `t1.idCity` anyway. There is no need to check `dr != null`

Comment: I reduced the model to these two properties in order to make it easier for you, because originally the complete code was written in Portuguese. 
Btw Thanks for the tips